# Horizontal TextViews ignore padding or margin on new line

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm attempting to have a view with four vertical `LinearLayout`, each one having two or three horizontal `TextView`.
The problem I'm having happens on the second/third `TextView` element. When the text is too long and it "goes" to a new line, instead of starting on the left of the new line, it starts on the bottom of where that element started.

The problem can be easily viewed in the following image:
[image: Android LinearView & TextView new line problem]

I've tried with `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`, modifying the `TextView` padding attributes without success.

My actual layout code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_beneficioDesc"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/beneficio_desc"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_nombre"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_kmsDistanciaDesc"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/distancia_desc"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_kmsDistancia"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_kmsDistanciaUnidad"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/distancia_unidad"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_tarjetasDesc"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tarjetas_desc"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_tarjetas"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_detallesDesc"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/detalles_desc"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/promocion_detalles"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        tools:context="ar.com.rouler.supromo.PromocionDetailFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it correct to use a `LinearLayout`? Does this issue have a possible solution?

Comment: *2x1 en Galletitas Oreo* is the text in `promocion_nombre` thats is not going where you want?

Comment: I don't think so that it is possible with any of layout or with any attribute of TextView. For such kind of functionality I would suggest you to use only one "TextView" instead of two or three text views. Just use one text view and concatenate all three strings pragmatically.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want it to do.  Are you saying that the second element in the horizontal LinearLayout should wrap all the way to the far left of the first element?  LinearLayout won't flow text for you like this.  You might instead want to concatenate the text and put it all into a single TextView if that's OK for your purposes.

Comment: @g20 Yes. `promocion_nombre` is the ID for that element.

Comment: @AdarshYadav @DougStevenson Yes. If what I'm trying to do can't be easily achieved, I'll add just one `TextView` per line, and concatenate the strings.

Comment: @FedeLerner That will be the easiest way as you are using same style for all text views so it will also not hamper you.